# Monotouch: Problems with Bitmap and references

Tags: bitmap, xamarin.ios

I have dll written with C# VS2010.
It has UserControl inside and also some public API.
Main idea of dll is to draw image.

Question 1:
I have public method which returns System.Drawing.Bitmap.
How i can show it in GUI, for example with UIImageView.

Question 2:
I added my dll as reference, wrote code (just constructor of my class).
Compiler says Could not import type MyType.
Why and how to fix.

Question 3:
I want my UserControl to be added to GUI. So i need to have ability to change his properties (these will be reflected on the image drawn).
How ?

Thanks

Comment: Alexander, welcome to StackOverflow. I hope you find the information you are looking for. May I recommend that you split your three questions up into independent questions? I believe you will get a better response that way.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot take a dll built in VS and use it in MT.  You must compile from source using MT.  Further, MT only understands a subset of the full .NET framework, so if your dll contains a UserControl it probably cannot be built by MT.

MT still relies completely on the native iOS API for all user interaction, it is not intended to allow you to use .NET UI objects/controls on iOS.